# How to correctly specify URL for ImageView in SceneBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have the following project structure:

```
src
    com.hello
        RootController

resources
    com.hello
        root.fxml
        image.png
```

In scenebuilder, I added an ImageView node then set the path to `@image.png`. It works fine in SceneBuilder, but if I run it in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:693)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.JavaFXImageBuilder.build(JavaFXImageBuilder.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.builder.JavaFXImageBuilder.build(JavaFXImageBuilder.java:37)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:763)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 17 more
```

How can I correctly specify the image path, given my project structure?

Comment: Do you use the `load(InputStream)` method to load the fxml?

Comment: @fabian Yeahhhhhh that must be it. I've fixed it by using `load()` instead of `load(InputStream)`

Answer (score 1):

In fxml file set the **relative path** of the image as the image path.

```
 <ImageView fitHeight="17.0" fitWidth="22.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
           <image>
              <Image url="@/com/hello/image.png" />
           </image>
 </ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that way.

```
private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

String url = "/images/cards/As.png";
Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(url));
        imageView .setFitHeight(726); //Set your image Height
        imageView .setFitWidth(500); //Set your image width.
        imageView .setImage(image);
```

Sometimes relative path can't identify the resource file correctly but `/images/cards/As.png` put the slash `/` to the `url` start it can identify the resource.

Hope you got the answer.